# Recursive system unique solution

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, recursion, matrix-rank

**General question**: How does one identify if a system of recursive equations (a slightly more complicated system than the standard $Ax=b$) has a unique solution?

**Specific example**: My system of two equations in the variables $x$ and $y$:

$x_t = x_{t-1} + a_t + b_t y_t$

$y_t = min \{1, \frac{x_{t-1} + a_t}{b_t} \}$

and a boundary condition $x_0 = 0$.

*PS*: I already have a solution for this system and think it is unique. But I'd like to know a formal way to prove this is indeed unique.

Comment: Solution is unique for $t>0$ because one can calculate sequentially: $y_1$, $x_1$, $y_2$, $x_2$, ...

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu yes, we can calculate these sequentially. But is that enough to say another solution does not exist?

Comment: $t\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose that exists two distinct solutions $x_t,y_t$ and $X_t,Y_t$. Solution are distinct then exist at least one $t$ such that $x_t\neq X_t$ or $y_t\neq Y_t$. Among such $t$ values exists minimal value $t_1$. Then $x_{t_1-1}=X_{t_1-1}$,then $y_{t_1}=Y_{t_1}$, then $x_{t_1}=X_{t_1}$. Contradiction.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu now I am convinced by your simple and succinct answer.